# com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl in java1.8 vs java1.7

Tags: java

Hi I am using below transformer to transform the xml

```
TransformerFactory.newInstance("com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl", null);
```

it works fine with `java 1.7` but for `java 1.8` name space order was getting different. Is there any way to fix the issue?

Comment: Please upload exact error or stacktrace.

Comment: This works good for me both in java 1.7 and java 1.8, you need to add more information.

Comment: created  transformer using below code 
TransFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance("com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl", null); 
and applied xslt transformation. in java1.7 its work fine but when changed to 1.8 test case failing by giving following. (1.8 name space order was changed)
<... xmlns[:t="http://xxx/xx/3" xmlns:q="http://xxx/xx/4" xmlns="http://xxx/xx/2]" languageCode="en-U...>
 but was:
<...xmlns[="http://xxx/xx/2" xmlns:q="http://xxx/xx/4" xmlns:t="http://xxx/xx/3]" languageCode="en-U...>